# GetElementsByTagName not working on XML

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, parsing, safari

My website calls a webservice and the webservice returns an xml. When I attempt to parse through the returned xml using `getElementsByTagName('*tag name*')` in javascript, safari gives the following error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('application_id')')

Does anyone know why this happens? The XML parses fine on internet explorer.

My JS:

```
function GetValuesFromXML(xmlText) {
    var string = xmlText.responsexml;

    var xmlDoc = xmlText.responseXML;
    var appIdArray = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('application_id');
    document.write(appIdArray[0].xml);
}
```

`xmlText` is the `xmlhttprequest` that gets returned by the webservice.

Comment: Please post the full JS code.

Comment: Have you tried using `getElementsByTagName(name)` (notice the extra `Name` at the end).

Comment: @jakeclarkson sorry i forgot to type that when i was typing the post... It returns "undefined" on any alerts or document.write i create using it

Comment: Is `"TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'xmlDoc.getElementsByTag('application_id')')"` the exact error message you get?

Comment: yes, that error pops up when i try set xmlDoc = xmlText.responseText... when i set it to response url, there are no errors but document.write posts "undefined"

Comment: @mzjn I manually typed out the error message when i was posting the question and made a typo

Comment: `xmlText.responseXML` is apparently a string, and `getElementsByTagName()` is meaningless on strings. You probably want to parse that XML into a DOM document before using it as one.

Comment: Hvae a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML for the answer.

Comment: This is why you should never, ever, ever, try to retype error messages. Does your OS not support copy/paste?

Answer (score 0):

Document is an interface, not an instance of a document object. Use [createDocument](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DOMImplementation/createDocument) to create an object, then append the responseXML to the document:

```
var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
dom.firstChild.appendChild(dom.createCDATASection(xmlDoc) );
```